# UWP Desktop e banco de dados

Tags: c#, uwp

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação para fins de gestão de negócios relacionados a locações. O trivial CRUD, relatórios, controles etc, comumente desenvolvidas em windows forms. Porém, estou fazendo uma aplicação UWP.

O dilema começa no fato de que aplicações UWP não podem acessar as classes ADO.NET, sendo assim a única maneira (que eu sabia) de apps UWP trabalharem com banco de dados é via WebService.
O problema é que estou tendo certa dificuldade para tentar encaixar toda a regra relacionada a persistência de dados dentro do WebService.
Busquei por informações de qual seria a melhor forma de fazer isso e encontrei sugestões de criar um serviço para cada entidade a ser persistida na base de dados, mas não acho uma solução muito prática e "elegante".

Também pensei em criar métodos de CRUD genéricos que pudessem persistir qualquer tipo de entidade, ou seja, um unico `insert(AnyType anyData)` para inserir qualquer conjunto de dados na sua tabela apropriada. Mas não consegui avançar no raciocínio, pois cada entidade é muito particular. Umas tem mais propriedades que outras, outras tem propriedades do tipo coleções (`List`, `Dictionary`), que serão persistidas em tabelas separadas (Exemplo: LOCAÇÃO e ITENS_DA_LOCAÇÃO), outras não tem, umas são extremamente simples outras mais complexas.
Em fim, criar um métodos de CRUD genéricos não é uma tarefa simples.

Quais outras solução eu poderia tentar nesse caso?

Comment: Não sei dizer se não pode acessar o banco de dados, pode até ser que não possa usar o ADO.NET, mas é restrição específica. Precisa ver se precisa fazer UWP, pode ser que não seja a opção mais adequada. Mesmo que faça e que **queira* acessar o banco de dados de outra fonte, existem diversas outras formas de fazer isso sem que seja um webservice. Pode ser que o UWP tenha alguma restrição que eu não sei, mas se isso for verdade pra mim ele ñ serve pra praticamente nada, até criar uma aplicação no iOS pode mais.

Comment: Quase tudo que tem na internet são soluções complexas para problemas que deveriam ser complexos, só que a maioria dos problemas são simples.

Comment: Resolvi fazer via UWP para tirar proveito dos recursos visuais do UWP. Existe o `WPF` mas UWP introduz muita coisa nova e torna mais fácil a criação de certos componentes que em `WPF` seria doloroso de fazer.
Para se criar um `HamburgerMenu` no `WPF` é um parto, já no `UWP` existe o componente pronto.
Você disse que haveria outras formas para trabalhar com `UWP` e banco de dados. Quais seriam?

Comment: Nunca usei UWP e não conheço bem, mas além ser ser claro que tem que poder, tem algumas coisas por aí: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/How-to-access-data-from-5f2602ec, https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-access/, https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2017/02/06/using-sqlite-databases-uwp-apps/#9u5tL2h4WuwOhpGr.97. POde acessar o banco de dados através de um serviço, mas não precisa ser webservice, talvez por TCP/IP, tem muitas formas

Comment: Caso seja uma aplicação monousuário poderia optar por `SQLite` (armazenamento local). Outras situações no momento não vejo uma solução que não seja algo relacionado a serviço. Não se trata exatamente como você informa na pergunta `'um serviço para cada entidade'`, um serviço atende sim todas entidades. Também estou começando a aprender essa parte de `webservice` dotnetcore já tem muito material sobre o assunto, junto com `efcore` já dá para começar a criar serviços. Trata-se de tecnologias recentes mas a tendência e evoluir.

Comment: A função do `WebService` não seria exatamente trabalhar com manipulação de dados e sim receber e responder as solicitações dos clientes. O trabalho de manipulação dos dados ficaria a cargo por exemplo de uma   `dll (Projeto c#)`. Recomendo (caso ainda não conheça) aprender sobre efcore (entity framework core) https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nesse seu caso, recomendo o estudo do Entity Framework Core, que poderá usar bancos de dados SQLite e cujo mapeamento é totalmente automático em cenários mais simples, em que cada tabela "filho" tem apenas uma tabela "pai".

Caso seja necessário que outras máquinas modifiquem apenas um banco de dados "central" poderá ser feito o uso de sockets, recomendo usar o Restup, que basicamente transformará seu app em um servidor REST, perfeito para esse tipo de caso, qualquer dúvida é só falar.

Comment: Olá! No meu caso a aplicação UWP deverá persistir os dados em um banco de dados na nuvem, onde outros usuário também irão persistir. Resumidamente será uma instancia SQL server no azure onde as aplicações UWP devem persistir.
Nesse caso você me recomendaria Sockets?

Comment: Sim, isso é o mais recomendado.